# Accessing PHP $_SESSION variables in jQuery and performing error handling and page redirects

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session, redirect

I'm trying to access PHP session variables using jQuery so that I can redirect a user using jQuery instead of PHP.  Right now, when a user logs in, a PHP script runs which checks a database for their logged in and registered status.  If the user is already logged in, they are redirected to a denied page using PHP and redirected to the registration page if they are not registered.  If the login attempt is successful, the user is redirected to their profile page.  What I have as of now works, however, there's redundancy when the user logs in.

**PHP**

```
    ob_start();
    require("../includes/header.php");
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
        $p_num = $_POST["username"];
        $pwd = $_POST["password"];
        ob_clean();

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `$user_table` WHERE `user_id` = '$p_num'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connect));

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $user_id = "{$row['user_id']}";
            $first_name = "{$row['first_name']}";
            $last_name = "{$row['last_name']}";
            $user_name = $first_name ." " .$last_name;
            $password = "{$row['password']}";
            $image = "{$row['image']}";
            $email = "{$row['email']}";
            $program = "{$row['program']}";
            $role = "{$row['role']}";
            $status = "{$row['logged_in']}";
            $registered = "{$row['registered']}";

            if(($user_id == $p_num) && password_verify($pwd, $password)){
                $_SESSION["id"] = $user_id;
                $_SESSION["user"] = $user_name;
                $_SESSION["program"] = $program;
                $_SESSION["pass"] = $password;
                $_SESSION["image"] = $image;
                $_SESSION["email"] = $email;
                $_SESSION["role"] = $role;
                $_SESSION["status"] = $status;
                $_SESSION["registered"] = $registered;
                $loggedin = "UPDATE `$user_table` SET `logged_in` = 1 WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id'";

                if($_SESSION["status"] == 1){
                    header("Location: ../pages/denied_login.php");
                }
                elseif($_SESSION["registered"] == 0){
                    header("Location: ../pages/not_registered.php");
                }
                else{
                    header("Location: ../pages/instructor.php");
                    mysqli_query($connect, $loggedin);
                }
            }
            else{
                header("Refresh: 1; URL=../index.php");
            }
        }
        echo json_encode(array("success"=>1));
    }
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#login").on("click", function(){
        $.post("../php/login.php", {}, function(response){
            if(response.success == "1"){
                location.replace("../pages/instructor.php");
            }
        })
    })
```

The redundancy comes with javascript's location.replace function and PHP's header function.  The script runs the way it's supposed to run.  So my question is two part.  Is there a way to do the error checking and redirecting in jQuery?  And.  Should I simply call the login script with a jQuery onclick handler and let PHP handle all the errors and redirects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access $_SESSION from the client side. What you need to do is output from PHP the "success" value and an optional variable that would represent the redirect destination if "success" is not 1.

PHP:

```
// lots of code
if($_SESSION["status"] == 1){
    echo json_encode(array('success' => 0, 'redirect' => '/pages/denied_login.php'));
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#login").on("click", function(){
    $.post("../php/login.php", {}, function(response){
        if(response.success == "1"){
            location.replace("../pages/instructor.php");
        } else if(response.success == "0") {
            location = response.redirect;
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Ah, ok, so I need to allow the PHP to run the error handling as is, and basically parse it into json and then let jQuery check the json encoding?

Comment: Yes. Never trust the client side validation. Always validate on server side at least.

Comment: Gotcha.  Thanks for the answer.  I'm not doing any client side validation, it's all server side, I'm just trying to make the project generally faster by having jQuery make the calls for me.  I'm accepting your answer.